# OSMNx: how to represent "MultilineString" objects as an OSMNx graph?

Tags: python, graph, osmnx

How to represent the data like the sample below as an OSMNx graph such a way the graph attributes are the 'properties' key in my data dictionary? I want to show the 'car' as edge weight in the graph for instance

> Given JSON-like dictionary
> data = [
> {
> 'type': 'Feature',
> 'geometry': {
> 'type': 'MultiLineString',
> 'coordinates': [
> [
> [4.84135339574847, 50.4752064026794],
> [4.83994049574887, 50.4755814026791],
> [4.83964539574895, 50.4756395026791],
> [4.83940939574901, 50.475673602679],
> [4.83911429574909, 50.475680502679],
> [4.83842839574925, 50.4755946026789],
> [4.83825849574929, 50.4755740026789]
> ]
> ]
> },
> 'properties': {
> 'segment_id': 9000004556,
> 'last_data_package': '2023-08-23 12:10:46.862000+00:00',
> 'timezone': 'Europe/Brussels',
> 'date': '2023-08-23 10:00:00+00:00',
> 'period': 'hourly',
> 'uptime': 0.731388888888889,
> 'heavy': 1.3353115727003,
> 'car': 25.9035764116655,
> 'bike': 12.2656825036358,
> 'pedestrian': 2.72979386848423
> }
> }...
> ]
> `

I am a bit lost regarding making it fit the "ox.graph_from_gdfs" requirement.